How do I remove Garbage Disposal plug once it has been installed?
We have hammered it and the plug will not come out.

By plug I hope you mean a stopper/sealing plug and not the electric plug.  Hammering anything in usually requires quite a bit of force to remove.  A picture of the plug you hammered in should give an idea of what type of removal tool needed to not break stuff.

Make/model # of disposal?

To those requesting clarification, there is exactly one reasonable interpretation of this question.  The factory-installed dishwasher "plug" that is just a solid plastic cylinder with a weakened end designed to break off if a dishwasher is to be attached.

@jay613 -- I think the OP was looking for the word "knockout"

Insinkerator, Waste King, And Moen all call it a "plug" in their documentation.  Why is there so much hostility towards a new contributor asking a perfectly good question?  Suggesting he wants to take a hammer to the power plug and correcting his correct language.    Why?

Drill it out or remove it and lay it on the floor per instructions.
If it's hanging from the sink, especially a stainless steel one, the sink bottom will absorb all the hammer's impact by bending and vibrating.  You'll only achieve making noise.  Maybe you could jam a block of wood between the disposal and a wall opposite the plug to firm it up.  Or maybe that will surprise you and break or injure something or someone.
Drilling seems obvious, why haven't you?

And you may need to rotate the disposal to a position where you can get a good angle on the hammer.  Make sure you hammer on something like a socket extension or a big scredriver pushed up against the knockout through the dishwasher drain port.
